# How to find out a list of locations at a given location on Android?

Tags: android, android-maps

My goal is to generate a list of all addresses at a given location in `latitude` and `longitude`. But I'm not sure how this can be done in Android.
My initial idea was to add a radius of length `L` to that location, then loop through all points in that circle to list all the addresses. However, I realize this method could take a lot of time, and the result might not be accurate due to the density of each area. Besides, how large should my radius so that the result is rationale to the user. 
I wonder anyone has done this before could share me some experiences? Thank you.

Comment: You're using the geocoder to get the list addresses right?

Comment: And you got the list of addresses being returned correctly from `getFromLocation()`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, I found one way to handle this situation is to use Google Place API and returns JSON array of places:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the maxResults parameter in the [getLocationFrom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29) method to make sure you limit your results to a reasonable number? Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Because the list of addresses from `getLocationFrom` is too little, most of the time it yields only one address.